# C: Count letters until specific entry inserted

Tags: c, strcmp, strlen

I'm a bit rusty on C. I'm in a school assignment that is asking me to make a program that gets user input, following that print the output. If the character count is higher than 50, to not print anything out and reprompt them. Quit should not print a count (in this case, 4).

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{ /*Start of main*/

printf("Type any word you'd like <= 50 characters.\nType quit to exit:\n");

char word[50];
int wordLength = 0;

    while (strcmp(word, "quit") != 0)
    {/*open of while loop (strcmp ... != 0)*/

    scanf("%s\n", word);
    wordLength = strlen(word);
    if (wordLength > 50)
        {
            printf("Try again, >= 50 characters!:\n");
            scanf("%s", word);
            wordLength = strlen(word);
        }
    printf("%d\n", wordLength);

    }/*End of while loop (strcmp... != 0)*/

return 0;
}/*End of main*/
```

I can't seem to get the length immediately following the submitted word. It appears to get wonky. It shows the number for the LAST submittted word after putting in a new word. It doesn't matter where I put the printf, it takes its time.

Can someone explain to me why it's so slow, and suggest a method I could implement to make it faster? This is a school assignment, please don't share direct answers, but guide me into the way I should be thinking? :)

I'm almost thinking this is inefficient coding with the delay.

You're all life savers!!!

Comment: [C-faq 12.17](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html)

Comment: the array 'char word[50]' needs to be initialized, since the first thing the code does is compare the first 4 bytes.  suggest: 'char word[50] = {'\0'}.  however, to allow for 50 bytes of input, the char word[50] should be char word[51]' to allow room for the string termination byte'

Comment: word-length can never by > 50 unless the word[] array was overrun, which would be undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: with char word[51] ... if( strlen(word) >=50)  { print overrun prompt;  memset( word, '\0', sizeof(word) ); continue}  to eliminate the second scanf and other problems

Comment: this line: ''this line: 'scanf("%s\n", word);' 1) has no size limit, so it could overrun the input buffer.   suggest: 'scanf("%50s[\n]", word)'  2) need to check the returned value from scanf() to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `\n` from first `scanf()`

```
scanf("%s\n", word);
#---------^
```

Thanks to @remyable, `\n` has different meaning in `scanf()` - not the one you are expecting here *to read newline*. Refer [C-faq 12.17](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html)

Also, checking for input for more than 50 chars that is not correct. You would get into buffer overrun. Look for different way to limit that.

Comment: The behavior of scanf when it encounters whitespace (i.e., a newline) is as follows: "A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails." (§7.21.6.2/5)

Comment: Thank you Rohan and remyabel! :) I do appreciate the explanations regarding **\n**!

Answer (score 1):

The code has multiple problems

- the `while` statement is using `word` before `word` is initialized
- the `scanf` doesn't limit the number of characters that get written
  into `word`
- `strlen` can only return a number `>50` if you overran the buffer
- the code only reprompts once, it should reprompt until the user gets it right